# Separate colors for stroke, fill

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet, polyline-decorator

I've added arrowheads along the path of a GeoJson. I'm wondering if there is a way to customize the stroke color to be different from fill color?

Here are the options I tried:

```
    {
      offset: "20%",
      repeat: "30%",
      symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
        pixelSize: zoom * 2,
        pathOptions: {
          fillOpacity: 1,
          weight: 0,
          // fill: true,
          // fillColor: "#c71002",
          color: "#c71002",
          stroke: true,
          strokeColor: "#fff"
        }
      })
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact `strokeColor` is not supported.

To achieve a border-like effect the following properties could be specified (from [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#path))

- `stroke` set to true (default)  - determines whether to draw stroke along the path.
- `weight` - Stroke width in pixels
- `color` - Stroke color

*Behind the scene `arrowHead` symbol is rendered either as polygon or polyline.*

Example

```
L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
  patterns: [
    {
      offset: "10%",
      repeat: "20%",
      symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
        pixelSize: 25,
        pathOptions: {
          color: "#c71002",
          fillColor: '#fff',
          fillOpacity: 1,
          stroke: true,
          weight: 2,
        },
      }),
    },
  ],
}).addTo(map);
```

Result

[image]